# How can I mass delete records from custom objects?

Tags: bulk-delete, cascadedelete

I would preferably like to use a point-and-click approach or an appexchange app which helps me accomplish that?

Also, if there is an app for recursive delete of data, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Is this a one off or ongoing requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Data loader would be the way to go (unless there is more to your questions).

Easy way, build a report the uses the criteria you needto select the records, , including the record id , export it, then use data loader to delete the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer console to run one liner that deletes around 10,000 records in each run. Assuming you want to delete accounts your code will be

```
delete([select id from Account limit 9999]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use workbench for deleting a single record or mass delete using csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can write a batch for mass delete. Logic should count the total no. of records and run the batch once for every 10000 records.